# Get tokens from a JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, regex, compiler-construction

I would like to write a simple internpreter in JavaScript/Node. I got an obstacle when it comes to generate tokens.

```
var code = 'if (a > 2 && b<4) c = 10;';

code.match(/\W+/g)
// [" (", " > ", " && ", "<", ") ", ";"]

code.match(/\w+/g)
// ["if", "a", "2", "b", "4", "elo"]
```

As shown, `W+` lets me get special characters and `w+` lets me get words. I wonder how to get those in one array, something like below:

```
// ["if", "(", "a", ">", "2", "&&", "b", "<", "4", ")", "c", "=", "10", ";"]
```

Comment: `\W+` is extremely naive, consider `(!a+-1)`, `/\w+|\W+/` will generate `(! , a , +-, 1, )` while the correct tokenization is `(, !, a, +, -1, )`

Comment: You cannot parse JS with regexp. It does not have the necessary parsing power.

Comment: @torazaburo could you suggest something better?

Comment: Yes, Write an actual parser using parsing algorithms. Unless you are doing this as an exercise, you would be best advised to start with one of several existing JS parsers, such as esprima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As shown, W+ lets me get special characters and w+ lets me get words.
>   I wonder how to get those in one array, something like below:

Simply try this

```
code.match(/\w+|\W+/g)
```

gives output as

```
["if", " (", "a", " > ", "2", " && ", "b", "<", "4", ") ", "c", " = ", "10", ";"]
```

And this will trim the tokens as well

```
var tokens = code.match(/\w+|\W+/g).map(function(value){return value.trim()});
```

Comment: Yet, if `code` is like `if (!a)`, I am getting `(!` instead of standalone `(` and `!`.

Comment: @DamianCzapiewski can you share the string you tried with?

Comment: `var code = 'if (!a)';` but then `&&` is what I'd expect so it seems to be no problem and that's work for another ops.

Comment: @DamianCzapiewski checked this input. I don't think from here on (till the stage I have given code for) you can rely on seperating tokens based on regex. You need to now iterate the tokens and seperate them based on JavaScript language grammer.